# Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

I'm getting a runtime error for the below code while solving the Pascal's triangle question on Leetcode:

```
Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior
```

I did come up with other code that works, but I'd like to know why I'm getting the error for this code.

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
    vector<vector<int>> v(numRows);
    vector<int> q;
    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
        q.resize(i+1);
        q[0]=q[i]=1;
           
        for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
            q[j]=v[i-1][j-1]+v[i-1][j]; 
        }
        v.push_back(q);
        q.clear();
    }
    return v;     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You construct `vector v` with `numRows` number of elements. And then you iterate from `0` to `numRows - 1` and in each iteration, you add a new `vector` to the and of `vector v`, so you end up with a `vector` holding `2 * numRows` number of elements instead of `numRows` number of elements.

Instead of `vector<vector<int>> v(numRows);` you should use `v.reserve(numRows)`. Here is full code:

```
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    v.reserve(numRows);
    
    vector<int> q;

    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
        q.resize(i+1);
        q[0]=q[i]=1;

        for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
            q[j]=v[i-1][j-1]+v[i-1][j]; 
        }
        v.push_back(q);
        q.clear();
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Or, you can get rid of `(numRows)` when constructing `v`, and then you can keep using `push_back()`. To avoid needless reallocations, you can use `v.reserve(numRows)` before entering the outer loop.

Comment: There is another problem with the code. `v[i-1]` is going out of bounds of `v` when `i=0` on the 1st iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for pointing for vector v size being doubled, I didn't realize that. I only had to directly index the positions in v and assign q, instead of using `push_back` and it worked.

Comment: And when i=0, the inner loop never runs, the inner loop only starts to run when i=2 so v[i-1] wouldn't go out of bounds! Thank you for the help :)

Comment: also, it has to be `vector<int> q(1, 1);` as 1 is the first element in the pascal's triangle

Comment: @John I'm not the one who mentioned the vector size being doubled

Comment: @John you are right about v[i-1], I totally missed that.